# Postfix with two vhosts

Tags: gmail, smtp, postfix

I've got this problem: I installed postfix (v. 2.10.2) on Ubuntu 13.04. I've got there two vhosts with two different sites, for example: aaa.com and bbb.com. Got those domains connected with google apps also, so I can manage my mailboxes there. Each of my sites send mails (registration etc) to users, but I manage only to use one smtp for both of sites. I don't know how to configure postfix to behave like this:

site aaa.com sends emails trough smtp.gmail.com using admin@aaa.com

site bbb.com sends emails trough smtp.gmail.com using admin@bbb.com

Please, help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure `Sender-Dependent SASL authentication` in Postfix. Please add the following lines to your `main.cf`

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf    
#...
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd 
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587 
smtp_tls_security_level = may 
smtp_sasl_security_options =
#...
```

and create `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` with the following content.

```
admin@aaa.com  username1:password1
admin@bbb.com  username2:password2
```

Do a `postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and reload postfix.

Ref: [Postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_sender)